# TMUX: Move to named window

Tags: window, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I already configured some keyboard shortcuts for myself in TMUX, but is there a way to quickly switch to a window by name and not by number? So each window has a name e.g. home. When I want to switch to another window by number, I use this shortcut: Ctrl-b number. But I can't do the same with names, e.g. Ctrl-b home.

How can I configure shortcut keys to do this? Is it even possible?

Thank you, because I can't find anything about this in the TMUX manuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. I found it in this blog post [Tmux the terminal multiplexer](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/).

The shortcut is Ctrl-b f name. This is a shortcut for the find-window options.

Comment: According to `man tmux`: `f           Prompt to search for text in open windows. `. In other words you are not just searching for the name of your window, you are searching for text in general. This should not be the correct answer.

Comment: And what do you propose then as the correct answer?

Comment: In the absence of a **jump to Window by name** shortcut, I instead use jump to window by index via `c-b '`  and type your 2 digits Window number to jump to. Another favorite is also `c-b w`.

Comment: @daparic `c-b '` also works if you write window name (case sensitive)